# Issue loading .profile

Tags: linux, user-profile

I am setting up a user profile for a specific application and I am getting an error that I have yet to encounter before. The error happens on with the loading of the `.profile` file, but the odd thing is that the clone of this server doesn't have the same issue.

The issue happens when suing to the user:

```
/home/dwadmin/.profile[19]: .[2198]: SetupRuntime[1543]: SetupExecutionPath[1150]: [: -s: unknown operator
```

Not sure where to being searching for a fix, nor what log would hold more viable information.

Comment: Could you post the line 19 of `.profile`?

Comment: Was able to solver the issue. The .profile thing was two separate files being sourced. The thing I couldn't figure out was that the .[2198], [1543], and [1150] all needed to be adjusted by 19 to find the actual lines that were having the issue. 

the line 1150 was double quoted "" when i needed tick ` marks instead.